# Mongoose: How can I concatenate the result of two sorted queries?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In my app, I have a list of stories submitted by users. The users can mark the stories as private so only them can see these stories. I need to retrieve a list of all public stories and the private stories of the user who is making the query, and it needs to be sorted so I can use pagination. So far, I have something like this.

```
story.index = function(req, res, next) {
    return Story.find({isPrivate: false})
        .sort('-date_modified')
        .exec(function(err, stories){
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }

            /* If the user is authenticated, get his private stories */
            if(req.isAuthenticated()){
                Story.find({ _creator: req.user._id })
                .sort('-date_modified')
                .exec(function(err, privateStories){
                    /* Create a list with all stories */
                    var all = stories.concat(privateStories);

                    /* If have something in the list, return it */
                    if(all.length > 0){
                        return res.send(all);
                    }
                    /* Return a 404 otherwise */
                    else{
                        return res.send(404, {message: "No stories found"});
                    }
                });
            }

            /* If the user is not authenticated, return the public stories */
            else if(stories.length > 0){
                return res.send(stories);
            }
            /* Or a 404 */
            else{
                return res.send(404, {message: "No stories found"});
            }
        });
};
```

But this is obviously not adding the private stories in order. How can I get this result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, why not just add private filtering in first query, instead of making 2 queries?

```
story.index = function (req, res, next) {
    var filters

    /* If the user is authenticated, get his private stories */
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        filters = { $or: [
            {isPrivate: true, _creator: req.user._id},
            {isPrivate: false}
        ]}
    } else {
        filters = {isPrivate: false}
    }


    return Story.find(filters)
        .sort('-date_modified')
        .exec(function (err, stories) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            /* If the user is not authenticated, return the public stories */
            if (stories.length > 0) {
                return res.send(stories);
            }

            /* Or a 404 */
            return res.send(404, {message: "No stories found"});
        });
};
```

refs: [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking exactly for that, I couldn't find anything about filters and the '$or' filter is exactly what I need.